# Translating PS1 Coloring from .bashrc to ZSH (.zshrc)

Tags: zsh

How may I translate the following coloring that I had previously on OSX `.bashrc` to work with ZSH `.zshrc`?

This was my original coloring setting with `.bashrc`:

```
export PS1="\e[0;32m\u@\h\e[0m \e[0;34m\W\e[0m \e[0;35m\$\e[0m "
```

With ZSH this coloring doesn't work (it's shown as typed in plaintext). How can I translate it to the color syntax that ZSH requires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zsh` is a bit simpler. Details can be found in `man zshmisc`.

```
# No export needed
PS1='%F{green}%n@%m%f %F{blue}%1~%f %F{magenta}%#%f '
```

You can change the foreground and background colors by name, palette number, or RGB specifications using `%F` and `%K`; no raw ANSI escape sequences needed (and hence no need to wrap them in the `zsh` equivalent of `\[...\]`; `zsh` knows how to calculate the length of a prompt containing its own `%` escape sequences). `%f` (and `%k`) restore the terminal default colors.

The other escapes map as follows:

```
bash      zsh
\u         %n
\h         %m
\W         %1~     Note you can choose how many path components to show
\$         %#
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanation helped me a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Those equivalents help me a lot I did not where to look.